# Why I am blocked from editing questions?

Tags: support, edits

I was editing some questions on Stack Overflow, after a while I received a message that I am block from editing posts.

What are the reasons to be blocked? Next time I will be careful not to repeat the mistake.

Comment: Just curious. 1. Why does this post get all the downvotes instead of flagging as duplicate or off-topic (too local, or because it cannot be reproduced - if the current close flag is correct)? and 2. Why was my comment removed linking to a site search for 'edit ban'?

Answer (score 9):

You aren't currently blocked from editing posts on Stack Overflow.

You were, however, warned about your recent edits in a message from a moderator. I see that you read this message a week ago. If you have additional questions about this, you can reply to that message.

Comment: I was blocked for about a week. Yes, now I am not blocked, just wanna know the reasons that I will be careful.

Comment: @Elyor - Again, I refer you to the message you received on July 31, which provides this in detail, along with suggestions about how you can improve your edits.

Comment: Yes, but what did the message say? What do the words mean? How are letters combined to create words? What shapes constitute letters? *[reductio ad absurdum omitted]*